# How can a NSObject know what view it was drawn in

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uiviewcontroller, uibarbuttonitem

If I want to extend a UIButton for example and have it present a new view. Can I create a method within my custom UIButton class to do this. If I initialize the button with a target method that ends up switching views it needs to know what view it is currently in.

```
ExpandedViewController *expandView = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"ExpandedView"];
[self presentViewController:expandView animated:NO completion:nil];
```

This is what the code would look like in a view controller, but how can I pass the view to the button so that instead of self, it knows what view to target.

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is that yes, this is possible.

The long answer is that you *shouldn't* do it because it breaks the rules of MVC.  Your button is a **view** and should not be acting as a controller (this is what the controllers are for).  Instead, leave the logic to your view controllers.

To get the correct view controller set as the target of your button, you can do this:

In `viewDidDisappear:` of your view controllers, remove the action for the controller that is going away from the button:

```
[myButton removeTarget:self 
                action:@selector(myButtonWasPressed:) 
      forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

And then in `viewWillAppear:` of your view controllers, add the action for the controller that is being presented:

```
[myButton addTarget:self 
             action:@selector(myButtonWasPressed:) 
   forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

Comment: I am extending UIToolbar actually. So I want the buttons in it to always point to the same view but they have to be able to tell the view the toolbar is currently in to present the new view

Comment: Whenever your view controller is shown, have it set the appropriate actions on the toolbar button.

Comment: @Inafziger's answer is cleaner, but an alternative is to have your button always communicate that it was pressed to the App Delegate, and the app delegate can detect the appropriate response / view controller to present from.

Answer (score 0):

Give your button a `containingViewController` property and don't forget to set it as you move the button around.